# python how to concert a string word to a list of letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a word:

```
'shrewd'
```

How can I convert it into:

```
['s','h','r','e','w','d']
```

I have tried:

```
delim = ','

x = 'shrewd'.split(delim)

x
```

But not working ,any friend can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any commas in your string, so you won't be able to get your desired output using `.split()`.

Since strings are iterable, you can use:

```py
data = 'shrewd'
print(list(data))
```

This outputs:

```py
['s', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'w', 'd']
```